Laravel Herd custom URL sites show "This site can’t be reached"
I'm new to Laravel Herd and not sure what I did wrong, I installed Herd from the main Herd page, on my Windows 10 machine, I installed it with admin privileges just like the docs say and everything went smoothly, however Herd sites don't seem to work here is what I see
URL http://test-project.test

Herd site page
General tap

Information tap

this is Herd version 1.8.
here are the things I have tried so far:

adding a "etc/resolve/test" file with the content of "nameserver 127.0.0.1" as suggested in this GitHub Issue comment
changing port number for the HerdHelper (the status usually is red and after changing the port goes green) then restarting services as suggested in this StackOverflow solution
changing DNS settings on chrome to make it 'OS default' like some suggested in this GitHub issue

None of the previous suggested solutions worked for me, any suggestions?
if there is anything I can provide please let me know.

I've found that If your browser is using private/secure DNS it may interfere with dnsmasq resolution for localhost

Similar to the above - disabling my VPN fixed it for me

For me, the solution was go to the windows Tray->Herd->Stop All Services -> Start All Services

this my first time ever writing anything here so bear with me. go to dashboard then quick access then open sites. top left go to add and add the wanted project. after that try visiting project.test.
i tried everything from everywhere for over 3 hours to come up with this solution by myself lol
i hope it works for you buddy

run this command:
%USERPROFILE%.config\herd\bin\HerdHelper.exe

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
